# Two Form Action that opens URL in a new window in One Submit button?

Tags: forms, action

Is it possible to Put Two Form action in one submit button?? the user will able to select two radio buttons and each form action will open the URL in a new window simultaneously. I don't know how to do it and I don't have much knowledge in coding. This code is not mine and I just want to modify. :(

here's the code:

```
<form action="http://thegreatpromocode.tk/lite/jonsnow/subscribe" method="post" class="form-subscribe-
promo" target="foo" onsubmit="window.open
('','foo','width=450,height=250,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no')">

        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="BlueGem">BlueGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="RedGem">RedGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="GreenGem">GreenGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="WhiteGem">WhiteGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="YellowGem">YellowGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="DarkGem">DarkGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="OrangeGem">OrangeGem<br>
        <input type="radio" name="promo_code" value="VioletGem">VioletGem<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="subscriber" value="temporary">
        <input type="hidden" name="promo_name" value="GemStone"><hr>
        <center><input type="text" name="User ID" size="18" onblur="if

(this.value=='')

{this.value='ID Number';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='ID Number'){ 

this.value='';}" value="11-Digit Mobile Number">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="http://thegreatpromocode.tk/lite/jonsnow/subscribe" 
    method="post" 
    class="form-subscribe-promo" 
    target="_blank" 
    onsubmit="
            window.open('http://www.google.com','New Window 1','width=450,height=250,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
            window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','New Window 2','width=450,height=250,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
            return false;">
```