# Replace text on page on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form to let people submit news articles to my site (a company intranet). Sometimes the form submission takes a few seconds to resolve due to some actions I have in place on the relevant model save method. I wanted to replace the text on the form page with a message saying "Sending your article. This may take a few seconds, please do not refresh the page." as soon as someone hits submit. I've seen these on a number of websites when buying things online.

My first attempt at doing this was to add an `onClick` event to the form button. Submitting then successfully replaced the text but did not submit the form. I had a look at [this answer on binding two events to one submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614334/one-form-one-submission-button-but-two-actions) but it doesn't seem to address my need as it looks PHP-specific. I'm certain javascript is the right tool for the job but I can't think of how to do this other that binding to clicking the submit button. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please show the code you tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is indeed the right way to do so. If you are using jQuery you can go ahead and use something like:

```
$('form#your-form-id').submit(function(){
    $(this).hide().after('Loading, please wait...');
});
```

Where `#your-form-id` would be the id of the form. This function is hiding the form content and showing that text, you could do anything instead actually.