# button has two actions at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

Can a button has two actions at  the same time?
1- go to another page
2- reset all inputs in both pages
I am using Intel XDK

```js
function register_event_handlers()
 {

        /* button  Grupp 1 */
    $(document).on("click", ".uib_w_8", function(evt)
    {
        /* your code goes here */
         activate_page("#grupp1");
        document.getElementById("date1").reset();
                 document.getElementById("date2").reset();
                 document.getElementById("dag1").reset();
                 document.getElementById("dag2").reset();
                 document.getElementById("Arbetar1").reset();
                 document.getElementById("Arbetar2").reset();
                 document.getElementById("start1").reset();
                 document.getElementById("start2").reset();
                document.getElementById("slut1").reset();
                 document.getElementById("slut2").reset();
         return false;
         
    });
 }
 document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
})();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614334/one-form-one-submission-button-but-two-actions... Go here..

Comment: I can not use onClick="document.location.href='some/page'" /> in intel xdk. Ican only use activate_page as above in my js

Comment: That was an example to use two actions on one button.. Chagethe code according to your requirment in both functions

Answer (score 1):

Set the button to run a custom script. In your custom script, just do this

```
$(document).on("click", "#mybutton", function(evt) {
   //this does the reset
   document.getElementById("date1").reset();
   //this goes to that page
   activate_page("#grupp1");
   return false;
});
```